# Javascript Regex to match everything after 2nd hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a JavaScript regex pattern to match on everything after the 2nd instance of the hyphen `-`

Here is an example:

```
/property/1-H6205636-1320-Edison-Avenue-Bronx-NY-10461
```

In this case, I'd like to only match the address so the desired variable to store would be:

```
1320-Edison-Avenue-Bronx-NY-10461
```

These characters `1` and `H6205636` can change in length so I don't think a pattern that matches on a specific number of digits would work.

From here, I'd be able to replace the remaining `-` hyphens with   spaces which I think I can manage

**Open to any methods if regex isn't the best approach here

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/GYwPoM/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above regex assume that:

- `/property/` can be any string until it start and end with `/`
- `1-H6205636-` is any number followed by `-` then by any string and end with a `-`.

```js
const str = '/property/1-H6205636-1320-Edison-Avenue-Bronx-NY-10461'
const res = str.match(/^\/\w+\/\d+-[^-]+-(.*)$/)[1].replaceAll('-', ' ')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.split('-')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), remove indexes 0 and 1 using [`.slice(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and then [`.join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array back together using a space. Though first split on `/` to get the filename (?) only.

```js
let property = '/property/1-H6205636-1320-Edison-Avenue-Bronx-NY-10461';

// get "1-H6205636-1320-Edison-Avenue-Bronx-NY-10461"
// after splitting, [0] is empty string, [1] is "property", [2] is the rest of the string
let propertyName = property.split('/')[2];

// split by '-' and slice out the first 2 values
let propertySplit = propertyName.split('-').slice(2);

// join it all back together
let propertyAddress = propertySplit.join(' ');

console.log(propertyAddress);
```